# Getting an array ordered

Tags: r

I would like to order and trasform the values of each floor's array (each one independently) from the biggest to the smallest value as in this example :

```
#My array:
a1 <- array(c(1,-4,13,0,1,0,-17,12,14,9,-3,-3),dim = c(2,3,4))
a1
, , 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   13    1
[2,]   -4    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  -17   14   -3
[2,]   12    9   -3

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   13    1
[2,]   -4    0    0

, , 4

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  -17   14   -3
[2,]   12    9   -3
```

Into:

```
a2
, , 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    1    2    #1FLOOR: 13 is the biggest --> (1); 1 is the second biggest --> (2); ecc...
[2,]    4    3    3

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    1    4    #2FLOOR: 14 is the biggest --> (1); 12 is the second biggest --> (2); ecc...
[2,]    2    3    4

, , 3  ecc...
```

For example if i do:

```
 a2[]<-factor(-a1)
```

It does not evaluate each floor independently, but rank values taking into consideration the entire array

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Use `apply` and the function you mention.

Answer (score 4):

Use `apply()` on the third dimension and drop the factor's attributes with `c()`.  If you don't coerce the factor to integer somehow, then the matrix automatically gets coerced to character.

```
a1[] <- apply(a1, 3, function(x) c(factor(-x)))
```

which gives the updated `a1`

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    1    2
[2,]    4    3    3

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    1    4
[2,]    2    3    4

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    1    2
[2,]    4    3    3

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    1    4
[2,]    2    3    4
```

Comment: If you don't mind Richard, what does a1[] mean here, I thought it meant create an array called a1[], but I tired it with an a2[] instead and it complained that object 'a2' doesn't exist?  It's assuming the object exists already so it can't mean create a1[].  I am not following

Comment: @user3507767 - It replaces the values in `a1`.  If you don't want to do that, you can do `a2 <- a1` first, then `a2[] <- ...` and `a1` will remain unchanged.

Comment: @user3507767 Specifically, the `[]` is a trick to keep the existing dimensions of `a1` the same and only replace the values. If you get rid of the `[]` the code will run but you might just end up with a vector without any rows, columns, etc.